# How to collect application logs in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am new to windows phone platform.Is there anything available like logcat in android for windows for collecting logs?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 8.1 introduced new classes to simplify logging. These classes are [LoggingChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.loggingchannel.aspx), [LoggingSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.loggingsession.aspx) and [others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.aspx).

Here's an example:

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
LoggingSession logSession;
LoggingChannel logChannel;

public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
}

void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    logChannel.LogMessage("Unhandled exception: " + e.Message);
    logSession.SaveToFileAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "MainLog.log").AsTask().Wait();
}

protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    logSession = new LoggingSession("MainLogSession");
    Resources["MainLogSession"] = logSession;

    logChannel = new LoggingChannel("AppLogChannel");
    logSession.AddLoggingChannel(logChannel);
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
LoggingChannel logChannel;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    var logSession = (LoggingSession)Application.Current.Resources["MainLogSession"];
    logChannel = new LoggingChannel("MainPageLogChannel");
    logSession.AddLoggingChannel(logChannel);
    logChannel.LogMessage("MainPage ctor", LoggingLevel.Information);
}
```

---

I *highly* recommend watching the [Making your Windows Store Apps More Reliable](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-136) keynote during the 2013 build conference, where Harry Pierson demonstrates these new APIs in more detail (including uploading the log file to a backend server using a background task that gets executed when the phone is connected to AC power).

Comment: Can i know where the log file is getting saved? Also can i copy that to desktop using isolated storage explorer tool?

Comment: You can see in my App.xaml.cs code that I'm specifying that I want the log file saved in my app's local data folder with the name "MainLog.log", so yes, you can specify where it gets saved. You should be able to use the isolated storage tool to copy the file onto your PC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am able to pull the file onto my PC.But that log file is not in readable format(like some junk characters).Is there anyway to convert it into readable format?

Comment: Try saving the log file with the extension ".etl" and open it in event viewer. Or you can execute `tracerpt MainLog.etl` on the command line to generate an XML version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *System.Diagnostics.Debug* to view the logs on Visual Studio Console Window but you won't be able to collect them later because it's only shown during debug.

I recommend the use of MetroLog, a lightweight logging system designed specifically for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps.

You can install it using NuGet

```
Install-Package MetroLog
```

Here's an quick example:

```
using MetroLog;
using MetroLog.Targets;

LogManagerFactory.DefaultConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, new FileStreamingTarget());
GlobalCrashHandler.Configure();

ILogger log = LogManagerFactory.DefaultLogManager.GetLogger<MainPage>();

log.Trace("This is a trace message.");
```

You can find a tutorial explaining how to add it on your project at http://talkitbr.com/2015/06/11/adicionando-logs-em-universal-apps. Also there is an explanation regarding retrieving these logs.